# How to download file from organization sharepoint?

Tags: python, sharepoint, request, office365

I am trying to access organization sharepoint using python script, but I am unable to do it. I have tried every python library in which we could do it. It might be possible that I am not creating correct request payload, but I have no idea how to create sharepoint request for a specific organization.
Thanks

I have tried requests_ntlm, requests.HTTPBasicAuth, office365, sharepoint and sharepy python libraries to get it done.

```
import requests

from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.runtime.utilities.request_options import RequestOptions

url = "https://organization.sharepoint.com/sites/BIRE/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=/sites/BIRE/Shared Documents/folder"

username = "user_name"
password = "Password"

ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
token = ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password)
print( token)
options = RequestOptions(url)
ctx_auth.authenticate_request(options)

req = requests.get(url, headers=options.headers, verify=False, allow_redirects=True)
```

I want to hit the URL and download the file with the given name.

Comment: found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you provide some kind of error message that you are getting. but from looking at your code - you are just missing the part at the end where you save the output to a file.

```
output = open('filename.xlsx', 'wb')
output.write(req.content)  
output.close()`
```